# Should I test for attributes on Models?

Tags: unit-testing

In my unit tests, should I test for attributes on the models?

If I have a model called `person`, should write a test to make sure that `person.name` exists, and is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not specify a language I will have to answer generally.

If you have a dynamic language then it is pretty important to ensure that your dynamically generated objects contain all the fields required (and those fields are also populated appropriately.)

As a general rule when writing unit tests simply just write the test, what damage will it do? find a bug?, let someone know that they have broken something which might cause a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It is always difficult to know when testing goes too far - i.e. if you have a method/property on an object that just returns the value found in an attribute, should we bother with tests that are so simple? Our strive for perfection tells us yes, but pragmatically it's not so simple, as you can end up with lots of extra tests that don't add a lot of value.

Constructors have always had a similar problem - if a constructor just takes parameters and saves them as attributes in the object, should we test this?

The approach I take here is for each class to add a test called `test_construction` to the unit tests for that class. This will construct an object, and then check the values for all of the methods/properties that look up these values. This gives test coverage for both the constructor and the attribute lookups, with minimal overhead of a single test.

However - if you or your team decides not to test these functions I would not worry too much either - any issues are likely to get picked up by other tests, and there are bound to be more important tests for you to write than these.